# Not adding songs from mpmediaitemcollection to nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c

App is crashing when adding songs from mpmediaitems.item . Code is

```
NSUserDefaults *playlistSon = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *dataa = [playlistSon objectForKey:@"xxx"];
MPMediaItemCollection *mediasongs = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataa] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *medialibraryArray;
medialibraryArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[medialibraryArray addObjectsFromArray:mediasongs.items];
```

Comment: I guess there is a crash log? Which is...? Potential issues: How do you save your data? Why the `mutableCopy`? If you save a `MPMediaItemCollection` object, `MPMediaItemCollection` doesn't comply with `NSCopying`, so that will crash, and that seems useless by the way. So `MPMediaItemCollection *mediasongs = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataa];`.

Comment: Thanks for reply  i got the crash reason -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: saving data though    NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:_arrCheckedSongs];
    NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [orderedSet array];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayWithoutDuplicates];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"playlistSongCount"];
    [defaults synchronize];